# ionic cordova platform add ios gives error

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I try to add the `ios` platform to my ionic project and I get this error after a little bit of trying:

```
> cordova platform add ios --save
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@4.5.2

Adding superagent project...

Unable to load PlatformApi from platform. Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (Does not appear to implement platform Api.)

Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (The platform "superagent" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. superagent not supported.)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Use: > ionic cordova platform add ios

Comment: try using a different release version
https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
ionic cordova platform add ios --save
```

instead